# Trying to display factors of integers, but having difficulties

Tags: java, class, loops, parameters, constructor

I'm new to programming, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this one.

Here is my main method:

```
import java.util.*;
public class DisplayFactors
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a integer: ");
        String input1 = scan.nextLine();
        int input = Integer.parseInt(input1);

        FactorGenerator factor = new FactorGenerator(input);

        System.out.print(factor.getNextFactor());

        while (!factor.hasMoreFactors())
        {
            System.out.print(factor.getNextFactor());
        }
    }   
}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class FactorGenerator {

    private int num;
    private int nextFactor;

    public FactorGenerator(int n)
    {
        num = nextFactor = n;
    }

    public int getNextFactor()
    {
        int i = nextFactor - 1 ;

        while ((num % i) != 0)
        {
            i--;
        }
        nextFactor = i;
        return i;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreFactors()
    {
        if (nextFactor == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently if I enter 15 as the integer I only get one factor back, which is 5, but I need it to display all the factors: 15, 5, 3 and 1. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you import java.util.Scanner; ?

Comment: `while (!factor.hasMoreFactors())` should be `while (factor.hasMoreFactors())`

Comment: @Dangerosking yes he did, you can see on first code line `import java.util.*;` that means all needed classes from `java.util` will be imported

Comment: @Dangerosking I did java.util.* which includes Scanner.

Comment: @Walery Strauch Oh yes, I didn't realise

Comment: @Katja Christiansen Ooh, I think you're right! silly mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
while (!factor.hasMoreFactors())
            {
                System.out.print(factor.getNextFactor());
            }
```

you say that **while there aren't any more factors, print them on the screen**, but you need
to **print the factors as long as they exist in the list.**

So in Java you will have:

```
while (factor.hasMoreFactors())
                {
                    System.out.print(factor.getNextFactor());
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!factor.hasMoreFactors())
{
    System.out.print(factor.getNextFactor());
}
```

must be

```
while (factor.hasMoreFactors())
{
    System.out.print(factor.getNextFactor());
}
```